# RxJava: Can I override OnError or create a custom Observable which handles a specific error

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java

I've come across an issue in my application where I am checking for a specific error (lets say error 9000) in the onError of many different subscriptions. All of them may or may not handle the error in the same way.  Rather than doing a check if(error == 9000) in the OnError of these subscriptions is there a way to create a custom Observable or operator that checks for this error specifically or maybe something like a .doOn9000Error()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a simple function `handleErr9000` which takes an Observable, and transforms it into one which correctly deals with error 9000. The `onErrorResumeNext` operator is what you need: It takes a function which gets the error which occurred, and can decide, depending on the kind of error, what Observable sequence to continue with.

```
public static <T> Observable<T> handleErr9000(Observable<T> o) {
    return o.onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<T>>() {
        public Observable<T> call(Throwable err) {
            if (err instanceof NumberedException
                && ((NumberedException) err).number == 9000)
            {
                // Handle this specific error ...
                // Then return Observable.error(err) if you want to keep
                // the error, or Observable.just(someDefaultValue) to 
                // substitute the error by a default value,
                // or Observable.empty() to swallow the error
                return Observable.empty();
            } else {
                // just pass on the error if it's a different error
                return Observable.error(err); 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[I invented an exception class named `NumberedException` for this example, you probably already have your own exception class for this.]

Comment: That helped tremendously...thanks for the help,  much appreciated